# How can PKCS11 be utilized in an Android application to read data from an eToken?

Tags: android, pkcs#11, e-token

I need to read certificates from an eToken, and I have attempted an implementation using PKCS11. However, I require the libIDPrimePKCS11.dll library, which is only valid for Windows and not compatible with Android. How can I include it in my Android project?

Do I need to convert it to .so format, or is there another solution?